# rails directory structure for multiple apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Coming from a django background, I'm used to a startproject and a startapp command.  I just got started in rails and so far I've only encountered the new command to start an application.

I was wondering what the directory structure and interactivity was supposed to be like if you have a project to hook up multiple rails apps?  In django, we use startproject for the main project and startapp for each individual app, and with a urls.py files we can hook up the routing for each app.

I've looked at the structure [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm).  Is this the structure of a project or a single app (assuming I want to make a project with multiple apps that need to be decoupled)?  Also, if I had multiple "apps" created by the new command, how would I link up the apps together (django allowed absolute and relative imports starting from the project directory and had urls.py to handle the url routing)?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Django, but my guess would be that the Rails equivalent is to use [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

With Rails engines you can "mount" your engine's routes inside your host application, for instance:

```
# config/routes.rb
mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/my_engine"
```

You can have this gem nested in your host application's directory structure, for example `app/lib/engines/myengine` if you wish, and reference it with the path in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'my_engine', path: "lib/engines/my_engine/"
```

Engines are very similar to Rails applications, but read up on the guides for the crucial differences.